# How to dump django data and load it?

Tags: django, django-models

I use dumpdata and loaddata to a file, but when I load, it says:

Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Nothing was loaded, why?

Comment: Can you please post your `commend` here? I mean how do you use dumpdata ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the problem, remember to add file type suffix when you dump the data. Like:

```
# python manage.py dumpdata >data.json
```

Then loading the data will be fine. No suffix won't work